# seting its own color and shape scale for different point sets in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to plot two sets of points in one plot, and I would like each set have its own color scale and shape scale. When I add the second color scale and shape scale, the first color and shape scale were replaced.

My aim is that each point sets have its own legend displaying its colors and shapes.

My dataframe(`df`)looks like this:

```
variable measurements set1 set2
a        1            2    3
a        2            3    4
b        3            4    5
b        4            5    6
c        5            6    7
c        6            7    8    
d        7            8    9
d        8            8    10
e        9            10   11
e        10           11   12
```

Here is my code:

```
p<-ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = df,aes(x = measurements,y = set1,shape=variable),colour="red",size=3)+
  #scale_shape_manual(name="set1",
  #                   labels=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  #                   values = c(0, 1, 2, 4, 8)) +
  #scale_colour_manual(name="set1",
  #                    labels=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  #                    values = c("red", "red", "red", "red","red")) +
  geom_point(data = df,aes(x = measurements,y = set2,shape=variable), colour="green",size=3)+
  #scale_shape_manual(name="set2",
  #                   labels=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  #                   values = c(22, 16, 24, 23, 11)) +
  #scale_colour_manual(name="set2",
  #                    labels=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  #                    values = c("green", "green", "green", "green","green")) 

p
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to munge the data into a different format
try this

```
rookie.df <-read.table(...)
library(reshape2)
rookie.df.m <- melt(rookie.df, id.var = c("variable","measurements"),
variable.name = "group")
```

Here's the plot:

```
ggplot(rookie.df.m, aes(x = factor(measurements), y = value,
 shape = variable)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = group)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("set1" = "red","set2" = "green")) + 
scale_shape(solid = FALSE) +theme_bw()
```

[image]
I might add you that you probably want to do facets

```
ggplot(rookie.df.m, aes(x=factor(measurements), y = value, shape = variable)) +geom_point()+ 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("set1" = "red","set2" = "green"))+scale_shape(solid = FALSE)+theme_bw() +facet_wrap(~group)
```

here's the plot:
[image]

or faceting on group "variable" instead (I like this the best as it allows you to see easily how the measurements cluster

```
    ggplot(rookie.df.m, aes(x=factor(measurements), y = value, 
    shape = variable)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = group)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("set1" = "red","set2" = "green")) +
    scale_shape(solid = FALSE) + theme_bw() +facet_wrap(~variable)
```

here's the plot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `ggplot(rookie.df.m, aes(x = measurements, y = value, shape = variable))` would be perfect for me. But I got an another problem is how to change names of the two legends, key names of the two legends and the relative position of the two legends.

Comment: You're welcome. here's a reference http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Hi, you are very good at using R,  I will read through the link carefully.

Comment: @ infominer, how to add `geom_smooth` for each group?